# How to plot dates against prices

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a dataset with in the first column dates in the form of `'dd-mm-yy'` (so for example (15-3-1978) and in the second column prizes. Now I want to plot dates against prices, but unfortunately

```
plot(dates,prizes)
```

doesn't work. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: and tell us what "doesn't work" mean. How is the graph you get different than what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always when working with **dates** use the functions around [**datenum**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and it becomes an easy task:

```
dates = {'15-3-1978';
         '16-3-1978';
         '18-3-1978'}

prizes = [ 42 
           19
           84 ]
datesNum = datenum(dates,'dd-mm-yyyy')
datesStr = datestr(datesNum)

plot(datesNum,prizes)
set(gca,'XTick',datesNum)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',datesStr)
```

---

[image]

---

Very convenient is also the [**datetick**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) function as an alternative option:

```
plot(datesNum,prizes)
datetick('x','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

---

[image]

---

Regarding your comment, have a further look at [**datetick's format options**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html#inputarg_dateFormat) you have various options. For a dataset like

```
dates = {'15-3-1978';
         '16-4-1978';
         '18-5-1979'}
```

using above code and additionally:

```
plot(datesNum,prizes)
datetick('x','QQ-yy')
```

you get e.g.:

[image]

[**Generally this article may be helpful for you as well.**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-dates-and-durations.html)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to only have labels at the x-axis at each quarter or each year? My dataset is very wide (I have a prize for each month from 1975 till 2010) , so all the labels overlay..

Comment: @Lotte have a look at my edit. Please consider also accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left, to indicate the system that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: A little question left; if I use this code: datesNum=datenum(date1,'dd-mm-yyyy'); plot(datesNum,prizes1),datetick('x','mmm-yy');  I only get labels at January, April, July etcetra but my I have data of each month..